# Permission automatically granted Android

Tags: java, android, permissions

My device is running Android 6 with MIUI 8, and it doesn't require for me to ask permission to access gallery.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivity(intent);
```

That's all I added to the `onCreate` method, and I haven't added the permission in the manifest? Why does it do that? Don't I have to grant a permission, before an app can access my gallery?

Comment: what is ur targetsdkviesion in gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it doesn't require for me to ask permission to access gallery

`ACTION_PICK` does not usually require a permission.

Also, your code does not necessarily "access gallery". It starts an activity. That activity could be one of several, depending on what the user has installed.

> I haven't added the permission in the manifest?

There is no relevant permission for the code in your question.

You may be thinking of `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and/or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. You might need those permissions to read in whatever content the user picks. However, you are not getting what the user picks, as you are using `startActivity()` and not `startActivityForResult()`.